# How to get all occurs of {{ somthing }} in a sentance using regex C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a sentance like

> Hello {{Bla bla }} my name is {{other  bla}}

And I want to get all occurs of  `{{ somthing }}` using regex

How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far and why that did not work?

Comment: As default has said: http://whathaveyoutried.com? Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please see [the Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: I used this before
Regex reg = new Regex(@"{{(.*)}}*?", RegexOptions.Compiled);
what it gave me only the first result

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "Hello {{Bla bla }} my name is {{other bla}}";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\{\{(.+?)\}\}").Cast<Match>()
              .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
              .ToList();
```